# Is there a way to optimize this loop for large datasets?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a dataset (python) in which I want to classify the difference from the past time by type (from -3 to 3) starting with the mean and std, the dataset is almost 700,000 long and it is taking a while to create the array with the classifications

```
def tipo_(x):
    dm3 = data.Diff.mean()-2*data.Diff.std()
    dm2 = data.Diff.mean()-1*data.Diff.std()
    dm1 = data.Diff.mean()
    d2 = data.Diff.mean()+1*data.Diff.std() 
    d3 = data.Diff.mean()+2*data.Diff.std()
    Type2 = []
    if x <= dm3:
        Type2.append(-3)
    elif x <= dm2:
        Type2.append(-2)
    elif x <= dm1:
        Type2.append(-1)
    elif x >= d3:
        Type2.append(3)
    elif x >= d2:
        Type2.append(2)
    elif x > dm1:
        Type2.append(1)
    return Type2 


Tipo2 = np.array(list(map(tipo_,data.Diff))).flatten()
```

Comment: what is your `data` variable? It would help if you can post a line with `data = ...` and put some dummy data there that would behave like your actual data at least. We also don't know what kind of container it is.

Answer (score 1):

An important performance flaw in you code is that you compute:

- *data.Diff.mean()* - 5 times,
- *data.Diff.std()* - 4 times,
- both above points multiplied by the number of elements in *data.Diff*.

Change your function to:

```
def tipo_2(x):
    def tip(xx):
        if xx <= dm3:
            return -3
        elif xx <= dm2:
            return -2
        elif xx <= dm1:
            return -1
        elif xx >= d3:
            return 3
        elif xx >= d2:
            return 2
        elif xx > dm1:
            return 1
    
    dStd = x.std()
    dm1 = x.mean()
    dm2 = dm1 - dStd
    dm3 = dm1 - 2 * dStd
    d2 = dm1 + dStd 
    d3 = dm1 + 2 * dStd
    return np.vectorize(tip)(x)
```

Note that *np.vectorize(tip)(x)* returns a *Numpy* array, so you
don't need to create any *Numpy* array from the result of this function.

Then compute your result as:

```
res2 = tipo_2(data.Diff)
```

I compared the execution times the following way:

1. Created the source DataFrame:

   ```
   np.random.seed(0)  # To get repeatable result
   n = 100            # Numberof rows
   data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n) * 10, columns=['Diff'])
   ```
2. Generated results with both methods and checked whether they are
   the same:

   ```
   res1 = np.array(list(map(tipo_,data.Diff))).flatten()
   res2 = tipo_2(data.Diff)
   np.array_equal(res1, res2)
   ```

   The result should be *True*.
3. Measured the time of your solution:

   ```
   %timeit -r3 -n3 res1 = np.array(list(map(tipo_,data.Diff))).flatten()
   ```

   getting: *510 ms ± 7.49 ms per loop*.
4. Measured the time of my solution:

   ```
   %timeit -r3 -n3 res2 = tipo_2(data.Diff)
   ```

   getting: *2.12 ms ± 87.7 µs per loop*.

Check on your own for bigger *n* (number of rows in the DataFrame).
The difference in execution times should be yet bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some masks to avoid looping over every element, i.e., use your whole data frame as input to the adjusted function:

```
def tipo_(x):
    x = np.array(x.Diff)
    mean = np.mean(x)
    std = np.std(x)
    dm3 = mean-2*std
    dm2 = mean-std
    dm1 = mean
    d2 = mean+std
    d3 = mean+2*std
    
    out = np.ones(len(x))
    out[x <= dm3] = -3
    out[np.logical_and(x > dm3, x <= dm2)] = -2
    out[np.logical_and(x > dm2, x <= dm1)] = -1
    out[np.logical_and(x >= d2, x < d3)] = 2
    out[x >= d3] = 3

    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the conditional in the mapping.  `(x-mean)/std` points to the result.  This means the whole calculation can take place in numpy.  This will improve the efficiency significantly.

```
np.random.seed( 1234 ) # Make results repeatable
data = np.random.normal( 500., 100., 100 ) # mean 500., sd 100, 100 elements.

def tipo_np( x ):
    mean = x.mean()
    sd   = x.std()

    working = ( x - mean ) / sd  # How many standard deviations from mean.

    result = np.floor(working).astype( np.int ) # to floored int. -.011 => -1

    result[ result < -3 ] = -3  # If less than -3 => -3
    result[ result >= 0 ] += 1  # If >= 0 add one
    result[ result >  3 ] = 3   # If greater than 3 
    return result
```

Timings on my machine with 1,000,000 items in data.

```
%timeit tipo_(data)
149 ms ± 5.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit tipo_2(data)
1.58 s ± 8.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit tipo_np(data)
319 ms ± 2.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

@Nyps' reply is significantly the fastest.  Probably as there's no division performed.